# Why is this Groovy code trying to cast?

Tags: groovy

Im getting a cast exception thrown at the line "handDetailList.each". I don't understand why my code is trying to cast a list to a "Hand" class? It seems to me that sometimes Groovy does strange things with casting....?

```
private Hand buildHands(List handDetailList) {

        def parsedHand = new Hand()

        parsedHand.setTableName(handDetailList.get(1))


        handDetailList.each {

        }
    }
```

I get the following exception (I have edited the exception, line 70 is "handDetailList.each {"):

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object <details of the list, omitted> with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'gameMechanics.Hand' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: gameMechanics.Hand(java.lang.String,........


    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:358)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:599)
    at advisor.HistoryParser.buildHands(HistoryParser.groovy:70)
    at advisor.HistoryParser.this$2$buildHands(HistoryParser.groovy)
    at advisor.HistoryParser$this$2$buildHands.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at advisor.HistoryParser.parse(HistoryParser.groovy:57)
    at advisor.HistoryParser$parse.call(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: i got this error when sending 1 parameter to a 2 parameter function , totaly threw me off course #hategroovy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`each` returns the list that `each` was called on.

You have said the function returns an object of type `Hand`, and as Groovy automatically returns the last statement in a method, it is trying to convert the list to an instance of `Hand` and failing...

What is it you want to return?  The `parsedHand` variable?

Maybe try:

```
private Hand buildHands(List handDetailList) {
    def parsedHand = new Hand()
    parsedHand.setTableName(handDetailList.get(1))
    handDetailList.each {
    }
    parsedHand
}
```

if so.

Comment: Great! I missed that and forgot that in groovy the last evaluated expression is the default return value. Thanks